# Puppet: Issuer certificate error when requesting certfificate from ubuntu 18 node to Centos8 Master

Tags: certificate, puppet

I am trying to configure a demo, cross-platform  Puppet Setup, that is
Puppet master on Centos 8 running puppetserver version: 6.11.1
Puppet node on ubuntu18.04 running  Puppet v5.4.0

However, when I try a test puppet run with puppet agent --test , I get error like below.
Looks like it is expecting a issuer certificate of Puppet CA , that is certificate of the root CA which signed the puppet CAs certficate.  This error is not present with centosMaster-centosUbuntu.

Can anyone helpout here? Can i copy this cert from the Puppet servers file on centos to the ubuntu node that is expecting it? If so what would be the location on the centos host?

root@node04-ubuntu:/# puppet agent --test --ca_server=puppetmaster.localdomain.com --no-daemonize --waitforcert=20 --verbose

Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.localdomain.com]
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.localdomain.com]
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.localdomain.com]
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.localdomain.com]
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.localdomain.com]
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.localdomain.com]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.localdomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Fixed

The issue was the version mismatch. Got the client to be as the same latest version as the master and it is working now. Cheers